# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error in oracle of a sql commandd

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried plenty changes but still i get the same error - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

```
Insert into EMPLOYEES_14
(employee_id,
first_name,
last_name,
email,
phone_number,
hire_date,
job_id,
salary,
commission_pct,
manager_id,
department_id,
dn)
Values
('101',
hazel,
page,
hazel@gmail.com,
'123456789',
to_date ('2019-01-01 08 00 00' 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS '),
 hr101,
 '10201.00',
 '20.00' ,
'123456' ,
'1001' ,
hazel is a good intern )
;
```

Comment: Why some of your strings quoted and some are not? Really do not understand the logic of query composition.

Answer (score 0):

The following is missing a comma:

```
to_date ('2019-01-01 08 00 00' 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS '),
```

it should read:

```
to_date ('2019-01-01 08 00 00' , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS'),
```

(and I don't believe you need the trailing space after SS either)

and you need quotes for all the string literals

```
Insert into EMPLOYEES_14
(employee_id,
first_name,
last_name,
email,
phone_number,
hire_date,
job_id,
salary,
commission_pct,
manager_id,
department_id,
dn)
Values
(101,
'hazel',
'page',
'hazel@gmail.com',
'123456789',          -- assume this is a string
to_date ('2019-01-01 08 00 00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS'),
 'hr101',
 10201.00,
 20.00 ,
123456 ,
1001 ,
'hazel is a good intern')
;
```

Comment: yes. thanks, I did notice that as well. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You should introduce date/time constants using the `date` or `timestamp` keyword.  The other problems are missing single quotes:

```
Values ('101', 'hazel', 'page', 'hazel@gmail.com', '123456789',
        timestamp '2019-01-01 08:00:00',
        'hr101',
        '10201.00', '20.00', '123456', '1001',
        'hazel is a good intern'
       )
```

Note that number values should not use single quotes.  So if values such as `10201.00` are really numbers, drop the single quotes:

```
Values (101, 'hazel', 'page', 'hazel@gmail.com', 123456789,
        timestamp '2019-01-01 08:00:00',
        'hr101',
        10201.00, 20.00, 123456, 1001,
        'hazel is a good intern'
       )
```